# Tuple to display keys in a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I want to create helper function to display all the keys in a tree-like structure for easier visualization.
Indeed, tuple's print is opaque.

My function should work like

```
tuple_to_display = ((1, 3, None)2,((None, 3, 4), 5,(6, 7, 8)))
display_keys(tuple_to_display)
```

`display_keys` in a command line should look like that:
[image: How should look like]

Could you tell me what I missed in the code below ?

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.key = key 
        self.left = None 
        self.right = None 
def parse_tuple(data):
    if isinstance(data,tuple) and len(data)==3:
        node = TreeNode(data[1])
        node.left= parse_tuple(data[0])
        node.right = parse_tuple(data[2])
    if data == None:
        node = None 
    else:
        node = TreeNode(data)
    return node 
def display_keys(node, space='\t', level=0):


    # print(node.key if node else None, level)
    
    # If the node is empty
    if node is None:
        print(space*level + '∅')
        return   
    
    # If the node is a leaf 
    if node.left is None and node.right is None:
        print(space*level + str(node.key))
        return
    
    # If the node has children
    display_keys(node.right, space, level+1)
    print(space*level + str(node.key))
    display_keys(node.left,space, level+1)  
tuple_to_display = ((1, 3, None), 2, ((None, 3, 4), 5,(6, 7, 8)))
tree2 = parse_tuple(tuple_to_display)#This is working 
print(display_keys(tree2, '  ')) #This give me none
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: It gives me none , it should give me like in the picture but from tuple to display keys like that did u understand me now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from `parse_tuple(data):` you should replace the second `if` by `elif`.

What you could also do is a `return node` after you first if. That should also work and maybe was your first intent.

Not doing either of the above means that what you return is `TreeNode(data)`

Next the fact that `print(display_keys(tree2, '  '))` prints `None` is completely logical since the return type of the function has no return. The prints are handled inside the function.

By modifying the code accordingly->

```
...
def parse_tuple(data):
    if isinstance(data,tuple) and len(data)==3:
        node = TreeNode(data[1])
        node.left= parse_tuple(data[0])
        node.right = parse_tuple(data[2])
    elif data == None:
        node = None 
    else:
        node = TreeNode(data)
    return node 
 ...
 display_keys(tree2, '  ')
```

I get

```
      8
    7
      6
  5
      4
    3
      ∅
2
    ∅
  3
    1
```